# How to see screen information at the top of terminal?

Tags: gnu-screen

I once used a server where using the screen command gave me a colorful header which told me the name of the screen, the total number of screens, the runtime, cpu utilization and maybe some hotkeys to cycle between the instances.

How can I achieve this header on my  Ubuntu Precise Pangolin server instance (I have admin rights)? As it is, I don't even see if I'm inside a screen or not.

Comment: as I'm unable to explain you what all this s*** means, please take a look here http://code-and-hacks.peculier.com/bash/setting-terminal-title-in-gnu-screen/ there's almost all what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify your `~/.screenrc` if you don't have one you can copy it with:

```
cp /etc/screenrc ~/.screenrc
```

and then add the following line.

```
caption always "%{rw} * | %H * $LOGNAME | %{bw}%c %D | %{-}%-Lw%{rw}%50>%{rW}%n%f* %t %{-}%+Lw%<"
```

You can change the caption to your personal needs.
Therefor you should read the [GNU Screen manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) especially the [string escape chapter](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#String-Escapes).

An alternative to GNU Screen is [Byobu](https://launchpad.net/byobu), it is an already configured Screen, may be you should take a look at it, if you want GNU Screen. You can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install byobu
```

And of cause there is [`tmux`](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) which is like GNU Screen with less glitches and it always shows a caption. But `tmux` has different key bindings and if you are used to `screen` you will need some time to adapt.  You can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install tmux
```